# How to config flake8 for Python 2 and Python 3 projects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, vim, flake8

I am working on multiple projects written in Python 2 or Python 3. `flake8` is already installed both for 2 and 3. It's OK to run in command shell.

E.g, running `flake8` on Python 2 project

```
$ python2.7 -m flake8 foo.py
$ python3.6 -m flake8 foo.py
foo.py:14:43: E999 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My question is how to config flake8 for different projects to choose py2 or py3? I had already created [`.flake8`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#configuration) configuration files for different projects. My editor is `vim` + `w0rp/ale`.

```
" ===== w0rp/ale ====== "
let g:ale_linters = {
\ 'python': ['flake8', ],
\ }
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_config_file='.flake8'
```

Comment: I assume there's a reason you can't virtualenv your way out of this, right?

Comment: @abarnert what plugin/config you suggested for vim? I am using `pipenv` now.

Comment: Honestly, I don't use vim, so I have no suggestion for it. But when you activate a 2.x project, `flake8` off the `$PATH` should just run the 2.x version, and likewise for 3.x. (Maybe only if you `pip install` it into each venv, rather than globally?) That works for me from emacs, and I think from the shell too. (Or maybe emacs just has 3000 lines of lisp code that work out the right one to call and I just never noticed…)

Comment: I'm a little confused. As you are using `pipenv`, why cannot you just use the python interpreter in corresponding virtual environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to configure anything.
What you want to do is use a virtualenv for each project.
Say we set up a project for Python 3, create a venv (or use a tool for that)

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv
```

Activate it,

```
. ./venv/bin/activate
```

And install flake8

```
pip install flake8
```

Now just open vim, you can check which python and flake8 installation vim is using with

```
:!which flake8
```

ALE just uses that.

You should also delete the line

```
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_config_file='.flake8'
```

Syntastic is a different plugin and you shouldn't be using it together with ALE.

Comment: For `pipenv`: (1) pipenv shell (2) pipenv install flake8